# What kinds of cryptographic algorithm i can use to sends/receives data to/from webserver?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

What kinds of cryptographic algorithm i can use to sends/receives data to/from webserver in iOS?(My webserver don't use https)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSURLConnection natively supports https.

**Edit:**

If you are looking to encrypt HTTP content across a normal HTTP connection, you can use Apple's [crypto services](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/Security_Overview/Security_Services/Security_Services.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000976-CH204-TPXREF102).  It looks like your options are limited on iOS.  You might need to use libcrypto directly.

Comment: My webserver don't use https. I just want to use cryptographic algorithm to encrypt data which sends/receives to/from webserver.

Comment: @leduchuy89vn: Please edit your question to add your comment to it.